# Python, using an Object as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

In Python, is there are method of using a reference to an object as a key to a dictionary?

Lets say I have a class as follows:

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.id)
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.id == other.id:
      return True
    return False
```

Then, if I create an instance of my class:

```
object = Example("My object")
```

Is there any way in Python to use the object `object` as a key to a dictionary, WITHOUT defining the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods?

As it stands now, if I do:

```
instances = {object: 1}
```

the later decide that I want to change the id of `object`

```
object.id = "Not my object"
```

I want the dictionary to "know" I changed the id, which it will not with this implementation, because the key is not a reference to the object itself. Is there any way of getting around this in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to do this. Out of curiosity why do you want do do such a thing?

Comment: What if you just don't define the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods?

Comment: @mkrieger1 That would have the effect of object identity being the basis for equality and hashing, which might be appropriate

Comment: You *really* want to avoid mutating objects used as keys where possible. At a minimum, you need to ensure that the fields that changes *aren't* used in the `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementations, or you're going to have some *really* confusing bugs on your hands

Comment: Best not to name something `object` as the built-in `object` is the basis for everything in Python.

Comment: You've written a lot of code designed specifically to produce behavior you don't seem to want. Do you actually want the `id` attribute to be involved in equality comparisons or hashing? Do you want the dict to care about `id` at all?

Comment: I am writing a mathematical computation package, and it is best done in OOP way. Some of these objects have different representations  depending on which object you ask it to use in calculations. I am storing all calculated configurations in a dictionary so that if the user were to request the same representation again, we can simply return it without calculating it again, as these computations can take a long time to calculate.

Comment: So the problem I am facing is, I really would like the reference of the object to be the dictionary key, but Python does not have something analogous to a pointer in a language like C. I need to in some way store the object or a reference of it in the dictionary as it is called upon when I perform calculations, but I would like to add a function that allows the user to change the ID of the object without destroying the dictionary, and ideally without having to modify the dictionary.

Comment: The only thought I really have is to create another attribute called `_private_id` or something of the sorts which remains constant after initialization.

Comment: I would also like to thank @Alexander for his comment, I have now solved my problem thanks to your initial comment. I will simply change my `__hash__` to return the id(self) which will solve my problem. :)

Comment: @JaredWogan You may as well leave it un-implemented, and inherit the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a method to change the keyname to a dict?
For example:

```
class Example(dict):
    def change(self, name, new_name):
        self[new_name] = self.pop(name)
        return self

x = Example({'hi':'Hello'})
print(x)
x.change('hi','hello')
print(x)
```